# Creating a "do nothing" driver for a broken onboard GPU

Tags: windows, driver, gpu

> **EDIT**
>   (Onboard) GPU's can't be disabled ("Do not use this device") and I've seen a lot of forum questions about how to fix this. *IF possible* I believe this could be a fix. Please do enlighten me: Is it possible to write a driver to disable a GPU?

I'm trying to fix a laptop with a broken onboard GPU, an ati mobile HD5000. (It's got an i3 CPU, so I don't *really* need it.)

All solutions I come across either disable the graphics card in the bios, or uninstall the driver and get Windows to not look for new devices anymore. The problem being: I don't have a bios setting, and I still would like to be able to plug in a new usb HDD, stick, whatever..

So I was thinking "huhh, perhaps I can write a driver that simply tells windows not to do anything". One slight problem: I've newer written anything close to a driver; no idea how they work.

**Couple of questions about this:**

1. Is it even possible to write such a driver?
2. If so, will this be days and days and days of work? (it's a rather old laptop)
3. If not, where do I start?

(other solutions are welcome as well)

Comment: In other words: how do i write a driver that disables a device?

Comment: That'll be weeks and weeks of work: you'll probably have to learn some asm for your GPU as well as its structure as well as lots of Windows-specific stuff etc.

Comment: Thank you, ForceBru.
So in other words it isn't easy to write an 'empty' driver..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/hh439654 and set your device and vendor id of the ati card in the inf file could work.

Comment: If your DSDT has it you could call the _DIS ACPI method for your graphics card to disable it. @maarten or just remove the device at all from the table, could work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the Device Manager and select "Disable Device". If you can't boot normally, Safe Mode should still work.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I'm looking for, because a reboot re-enables the device, uninstalling the drivers doesn't help because windows will reinstall them, and I don't wont to disable windows auto-driver installation for new devices.
So I'm looking for a more permanent solution.